# VisualSVN Server on ec2 amazon server setup : ERROR could not connect to server

Tags: amazon-ec2, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN Server. I can check in and check out on the server. When I try and connect from another computer. I get an error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
 'https://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8443/svn/CollectIT/trunk'
OPTIONS of 'https://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8443/svn/AppName/trunk': could not connect
 to server (https://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8443)
```

The server name is ec2-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com. When I ping the server XXX.XX.XX.XXX I get request time out

I've turned off ther firewall on the server

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your URL may look something like this: "https://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/svn/AppName/trunk". See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=331054